# How to fail the whole the primary process if one of the background processes fails in bash?

Tags: bash, gitlab-ci

So basically I need to

- run `stubs`, `server` and `wait` simultaneously
- when `wait` completes, run `tests`
- if `stubs` or `server` fail, the main process with `wait` and `tests` should fail too (because otherwise it stays hanging in there till 1 hour timeout)

The rest of the gibberish is my original question:
I'm running e2e tests in gitlab ci. the simplified script is this:

```
stubs & server & wait-on && test
```

wait-on is checking when the server starts responding on a specific url and after that the tests start running. The question is how do I fail the whole ci job if `stubs` or `server` fails?

In a sunny day scenario they run in background till the tests finish running and the container gets killed, but how do I kill the container in a rainy day scenario when at least one of them can't compile?

Update: It seems I didn't make myself clear, I am sorry. so there are 2 scenarios:

1. sunny: stubs and server are compiled and are run in background forever (till the container gets killed after `test` is completed) - this works as expected
2. rainy: `stubs` or `server` couldn't compile. in this case wait-on will wait forever till the container is killed by timeout  (1 hour in my case) - this is what I want to improve: I don't want to wait for an hour, but finish everything with an error as soon as `stubs` or `server` had failed

Thanks for helping, I'm really bad with bash, sorry

Comment: Just `wait` on background processes. What is the point `&& test` ? `test` will always exit with non-zero exit status if executed without arguments.

Comment: Include a [mre].

Answer (score -1):

You can kill the main test process if stubs or server fails using pkill

```
{ stubs || pkill -f test; } & { server || pkill -f test; } & wait-on && test
```

thanks to [chepner](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62729200/how-to-fail-the-whole-the-primary-process-if-one-of-the-background-processes-fai/62729535?noredirect=1#comment110930616_62729535)

Comment: `&` terminates a pipeline, not a list. This runs `stubs` in the foreground, and if it ever fails, runs `pkill -f test` in the background. Try `{ stubs; pkill -f test; } &` instead.

Answer (score -1):

Just check the exit status of background processes.

```
stubs &
stubspid=$!
server &
serverpid=$1
if wait-on && wait "$stubspid" && wait "$serverpid"; then
    echo "SUCCESS"
else 
    echo "FAILURE"
fi
```

Comment: I didn't downvote, but this won't work if in a successful run `stubs` and `server` simply run forever. But assuming `wait-on && test` succeed, you can probably kill both `stubs` and `server` and declare success. If either background process fails, then `test` should fail. (If it doesn't, then the test isn't doing its job correctly.)

Comment: Och, I understood `server` and `stubs` just quit after `wait-on` is finished because of the "ci job" reference - I assumed it's some kind of run ci/cd pipeline job, `wait-on` tests that something works, and then everything quits including background processes. I think unless OP specifies what it is, we can only guess.

Comment: I was under the impression that both the startup code and the tests were part of the same pipeline. The `if` statement would really be something like `if wait-on && tests && wait "$stubsid" && wait "$serverpid"; then`, so the pipeline doesn't exit until the two background jobs complete.